# Kind of a silly question, but need confirmation regarding the closed unit interval $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

I know that $[0,1]$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since its complement $(-\infty,1) \cup (1, \infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, $(0,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but is it an open subset of the unit interval $[0,1]$? My feeling is that perhaps it is an open subspace of $[0,1]$, correct? Seems like a silly question to me, but I would just like some confirmation on whether my intuition was correct or not.

Comment: What is the difference between a subset and a subspace?

Comment: What definition of "open" are you using? $(0,1)$ does not contain its boundary points...

Comment: If by subspace you refer to vector spaces, no; $(0,1)$ is an open sub**set** of $[0,1]$ (as $(0,1)=(0,1)\cap[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ is an open of $\mathbb{R}$), but it is not a sub**space** — since $[0,1]$ is not a vector space to begin with.

Comment: @StefanH. A subset doesn't have a topology - it is just a set. A subspace is a subset given the subspace topology.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I know, but in the question the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @StefanH.: Well, by definition, say $[0,1]$ has a topology $\mathcal{T}$, then if $(0,1)$ is a subset of $[0,1]$, the collection $\mathcal{T}_{(0,1)}$ of sets $U \cap (0,1)$ with $U \in \mathcal{T}$ open is the subspace topology and so that will make $(0,1)$ an open subspace of $[0,1]$. I guess in that regard, I don't see a difference, but I don't think this is always the case is it?

Comment: @Libertron What does $\mathcal T_{(0,1)}$ have to do with this problem - the question is about the an open subset of $[0,1]$, so the topology we are looking for is the topology on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Libertron: That's right, this is how we define the subspace topology (one can as well define it as the initial topology with respect to the inclusion map). But a subset is not open as a subspace, it is either an open subset or not. I was just curious why you italized the word *subspace*

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I was just generalizing some sort of topology, but I now see that the subspace topology is what I needed.

Comment: @Libertron: You need the subspace topology on $[0,1]$ when you want to know if $(0,1)$ is open, but the subspace topology on $(0,1)$ is irrelevant.

Comment: OK now I'm clear. Btw, Stefan I undid the italics to put your curiosity to rest, lol. Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are placing the subspace topology on $[0,1]$, then yes: the open subsets of $[0,1]$ are precisely those sets of the form $U\cap [0,1]$, where $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open. Since $(0,1)=(0,1)\cap[0,1]$, and $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, it is also open as a subset of $[0,1]$.